# Find matches from 2 tables, change other field?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two separate tables. One table (T1) has 400+ values in its only column, while the other (T2) has 14,000+ rows and multiple columns.

What I need to do is to compare the column in T1 to one column in T2. For every matching value, I need to update a different value in the same row in T2.

I know this is pretty easy and straight-forward, but I'm new to MySQL and trying to get this down before I go back to other things. Thanks a ton in advance!

EDIT: Here's what I've been trying to no avail..

```
UPDATE `apollo`.`Source`, `apollo`.`Bottom`
SET `Source`.`CaptureInterval` = '12'
WHERE `Bottom`.`URL` LIKE `Source`.`SourceID`
```

EDIT 2:

A little clarification:

apollo.Bottom and apollo.Source are the two tables.

apollo.Bottom is the table with one column and 400 records in that column.

I want to compare Bottom.URL to Source.SourceID.  If they match, I want to update Source.CaptureInterval to 12.

Comment: `Source.SourceID` and  `Bottom.URL` columns are of same type?

Comment: Yes, they're both varchar(32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to update.  But the performance will be much better if you index `URL` and `SourceID` columns in both tables as they are being used in the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE `apollo`.`Source`, `apollo`.`Bottom`
SET `Source`.`CaptureInterval` = '12'
WHERE `Bottom`.`URL` = `Source`.`SourceID`
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work.  I actually had a formatting issue when importing from a CSV file.  But all is resolved and working.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables together and do a [multiple table update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

Start with something like this:

```
UPDATE `apollo`.`Source`
  INNER JOIN `apollo`.`Bottom` ON `apollo`.`Bottom`.`URL` = `apollo`.`Source`.`SourceID` 
SET `apollo`.`Source`.`CaptureInterval` = '12';
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work.  I actually had a formatting issue when importing from a CSV file.  But all is resolved and working.  Thanks again!